# Vim: Combining autocmd?

Tags: vim, autocmd

I need to do the logical-and of two autocmd events in vim. Basically, the command has to run on an InsertLeave when the FileType is tex. It seems like this should work (in a .vimrc):

```
autocmd FileType tex :autocmd InsertLeave :w
```

But it doesn't. The nested option doesn't seem to help either, even though the manual indicates it should.

Its easy to do a logical-OR:

```
autocmd BufEnter,BufLeave ...
```

it mustn't be too hard to do a logical-AND.

Comment: You should take the ZyX’s solution as answer, since it solves the local buffer problem of Eevee’s.

Comment: Done, but I'm taking your word for it. I seem to remember the local buffers problem, but I haven't written latex in years, and switched to emacs 2 years ago.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have a correction to @Eevee answer: to make autocommand work for one buffer only, you should use

```
augroup TexAutoWrite
    autocmd FileType tex :autocmd! TexAutoWrite InsertLeave <buffer> :update
augroup END
```

, see `:h autocmd-buflocal.

Comment: This is brilliant. Now I can re-render asciidoc documents on switching to my browser.

Comment: Ouch. Problem: The second autocommand added up *every time* you switch to a tex file. After a short time vim starts to save lots of times in a row after you leave insert mode.

Comment: Whoa, it’s that easy to prevent it? Okay…

Answer (score 4):

InsertLeave still needs a parameter.

This works for me:

```
autocmd FileType tex :autocmd InsertLeave * :w
```

Note that this behavior will remain if you later edit a non-`tex` file in the same buffer.  I'm not sure if there's a simple way to remove it when editing anything *but* a certain type of file.

Comment: The colon is not really needed. e.g. `au FileType go au VimLeave * call system("killall gocode")`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the pattern option of the autocmnd.

```
autocmd InsertLeave *.tex w
```

Comment: This does not work when the file extension does not match the filetype or doesn't exist. That happens when you're doing things like comparing against backup/temp files, or if the location of the file determines its type, e.g. system configuration files.