# Get vim to provide tab completion for CSS class and ID names

Tags: vim

The one IDE feature that I always missed and invariably plug into vim is tab completion.

I'm a big fan of [SuperTab](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1643), but one thing I can't stand is the fact that it treats the parts of CSS class names and IDs with dashes as individual words.

I've found a couple of possible solutions for camelCase and underscore_completion but I can't seem to find anything that supports plain-old-dashes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not a CSS-specific problem: Vim uses the value of `iskeyword` to perform completion.

Type `:set iskeyword?` to see what characters are considered to be part of keywords. The default on a Mac is supposed to be `@,48-57,_,192-255`.

You can add the dash to the list with this command:

```
:set iskeyword+=-
```

Add this line to your `~/.vimrc` to make this setting stick:

```
set iskeyword+=-
```

Comment: I've tried that route, but that has the side effect that motion commands then treat the dash as a separate words. So my-class-name gets treated as 5 words when moving around the file.

Comment: Do you mean `eEwWbB`? The point is precisely to include `-` in what Vim considers a word. With the default value you would have to hit `5e` to go from `.` to the last char in `.social-network-buttons` but with `:set iskeyword+=-` you only need to hit `e` once.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear what I meant to say is that I like the default motion where dashes are treated as word breaks, but I guess I can change my muscle memory to use f- since I want full completion more often than motion.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work for me:

```
autocmd FileType css,scss set iskeyword=@,48-57,_,-,?,!,192-255
```

Taken from here: [VIM: How to autocomplete in a CSS file with tag ids and class names declared in HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559737/vim-how-to-autocomplete-in-a-css-file-with-tag-ids-and-class-names-declared-in)

Answer (score 1):

For future readers: if you want the benefits of dashes for edit/movement commands, but want full property autocompletion, try adding this to your `.vimrc`:

```
augroup css_dash_autocompletion
    autocmd FileType scss,css autocmd! css_dash_autocompletion InsertEnter <buffer> set isk+=-
    autocmd FileType scss,css autocmd css_dash_autocompletion InsertLeave <buffer> set isk-=-
augroup END
```

The first `!` prevents duplicate event firing. Thanks to [ZyX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5264606/315024) for the structure. If you re-`source` your `.vimrc`, you will need to `:e` any (S)CSS files you have open to pick up the change.